# find $(x/y)^{x-y}$ as a decimal to the nearest tenth.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me with this? Following shows what I have done.

> If $x^y=1278$ and $y^x=343$, find $(x/y)^{x-y}$ as a decimal to the nearest tenth.

I understand that $(x/y)^{x-y}=(x^{x-y}/y^{x-y})=(x^x/x^y)*(y^y/y^x)=(x^x*y^y)/(x^y*y^x/)$. $x^y$ and $y^x$ are given, what are $x^x$ and $y^y$? May be my method is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If approximation methods are allowed, you can graph the two equivalent equations, find the intersection of those graphs, and calculate the desired expression.

[image]

As you can see, the result is 6.3, to the nearest tenth.

If you cannot find the intersection of the two graphs, you can subtract their function expressions and find where that equals zero.